# How to refresh widgets inside a dojo TitlePane on Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo

I have the following **setup**:

- I have a `TitlePane` in my page, which contains four `ValidationTextBox` widgets inside it.
- The fields have some values by default.

The **problem** is:

- On Internet Explorer, when the `TitlePane` is expanded, the contents of the text fields are rendered outside the fields.
- If I move my mouse pointer, the text jumps back to place. It is as if the widget is waiting for some user action (eg. mouse motion here) to redraw itself.

The Dojo version is **1.5** (yes, pretty old, but we *have* to use it).

I tried setting focus to the first TextField through code. It didn't help.

Is there any way to force a widget refresh so that the contents of child widgets are in proper place?

Comment: Have you tried setting focus on the widget? You could always remove focus straight after again.

Comment: @Jez, yes, I tried focusing on the Widget. But that didn't help. I used the javascript `focus()` method. Not sure if there is a Dojo way of doing it.

Comment: There is a `focus()` method on the `ValidationTextBox`

Comment: Tried that too.. no luck :(